# How to extra two date attributes to build a new text string

Tags: xslt-1.0

Here is a sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Version2.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="4" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0" CircuitVisit="0">
        <Date ThisWeek="W20200831" NextWeek="W20200907">August 31–​September 6</Date>
    </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

Here is a stripped down XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:param name="CSSFile1"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="containerPage">
          <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
            <div class="containerMeeting">
              <!-- Put output here -->
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am interested in this element:

```
<Date ThisWeek="W20200831" NextWeek="W20200907">August 31–​September 6</Date>
```

Specifically, these attributes:

- `ThisWeek="W20200831"`
- `NextWeek="W20200907"`

The values are in the format of: `WYYYYMMDD`.

I need to display this text, for example:

> Schedule date range - 31/08-6/09

The tasks I need to acheive:

- Extract `DD` from `ThisWeek` (strip any leading `0`).
- Extract `MM` from `ThisWeek` (do not strip leading `0`).
- Extract `DD` from `NextWeek` and subtract 1 (strip any leading `0`).
- Extract `MM` from `NextWeek` (do not strip leading `0`).

I realise that is might not be straightforward because we want to subtract **1 day** which could theoretically be in the previous month. So if it is easier we could add 6 days to `ThisWeek`.

Can this be acheived with XSLT-1?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what difference it makes if you add 6 days to the start or subtract 1 day from the end. You can do either one using the method posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412319/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks. How do I make my ThisWeek value compatible with the $today variable in your linked answer?

Comment: Just extract the individual components - year, month and day - using the `substring()` function. For example, make $month = `substring(Date/@ThisWeek, 6, 2)`.